# How to adapt jssor slider code to a Drupal 7 node

Tags: drupal, jssor

I have a paid account with you and I tried recently to export a jssor slideshow in order to put it in a Drupal 7 block.

I exported it according to the different possible ways :

- download standard code
- download jquery code
- download minimized code

and I have always the same problem : the left and right arrow do not work and each time I edit the code in the node copied from the html page inside the zipped file the following syntax is never present :

Finally I chose the minimized code as I found it was better in order to avoid conflicts with other active js scripts in Drupal.

I pasted the js script is in the Drupal template "html.tpl.php" and the slideshow works automatically with the autoplay function but when I click the left and right arrows, the slides do not change.
Could you tell me however how to display the arrows vertically centered and to make them turn the slides as they supposed to do when clicked ?
Is there a known bug with Drupal 7 or a special way to adapt the code to the CMS ?
Thanking you in advance,
Best regards,
Corinne

Comment: Hello again, I found a solution by replacing the script named "jssor.slider-26.1.5.min.js" by "jssor.slider-23.1.6.mini.js" and the nav arrows work. Anyway the attribute data-autocenter="2" seems not to be recognized by Drupal. Sorry for the disturbance. Regards

Comment: No, you don't have payed account with me.